# VBA Macro Update List

Tags: excel, vba

I need to make a macro that makes a update from a sheet to another.

I one sheet i have a row with information that is update all the time (manually) and i have to check in another sheet on a column if this information is already here if not make an update and write new information on this column.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Update()
Dim Final As Worksheet
Dim Actual As Worksheet
Dim recRow As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim recCol As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim fcell As Range
Dim i As Long

Set Roles = Worksheets("Actual")
Set Final = Worksheets("Final")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

recRow = 1

With Actual
lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
Set colcount = Final.Range("A:A").Find(what:=.Cells(i, "A").Value, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
If Not fcell Is Nothing Then
recRow = fcell.Row

Else
.Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Copy
Final.Cells(recRow + 1, "A").EntireRowInsert
recRow = recRow + 1


End If
Next i

End With




Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question or issue?

Comment: When i transfer row`s from sheet1 in sheet1 all the data are arange in rows and i want to putt new data all in one collum.